# jQuery To Dynamically Resize Height Of Element To Viewport

Tags: jquery

I'm having some problems getting a jQuery script to work properly. I need my header element to  be the height of my viewport. The problem is, it doesn't expand the height of my viewport unless I click to inspect element, or change my browser size. Which I find odd since it isn't the height of the viewport on page load, but becomes so if I tamper with it.

Here is what I am using:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).resize(function(){
        var newheight = $(window).height();      
        $("header.full-header").height(newheight);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire the resize event again after the function, i.e.:

```
$(window).resize(function (){
    // All your code here
    var newheight = $(window).height();      
    $("header.full-header").height(newheight);
}).resize();
```

Should work now, as you're firing the resize onload by chaining.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call the function once on page load, as the resize doesn't fire until the window has been resized.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    doResize(); // run once on page load
    $(window).resize(doResize); // run on every resize
});
function doResize(){
    var newheight = $(window).height();      
    $("header.full-header").height(newheight);
}
```